# How to handle Frontend User Permissions in ReactJs or NextJs apps

Tags: node.js, next.js, user-permissions, user-roles

I’m working on an application that will have multiple role based users.

I wanted to understand how I can store permissions for the Frontend so I can display the right component.

I have tried to store the permissions inside a JWT but as per some articles, that’s not recommended.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "store" permissions for the Frontend? Normally you just request them from the backend and put them in a variable. If you're asking about how to implement an entire authentication system that's a bit too vague to get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use two ways to manage permission for users to access several contents or pages.

First, you can use a JWT in client with [jwt-decode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode) lib that decodes JWT without any key. So, your key security and low-level permission is done.

Second, you MUST control the access of users to sensitive data and pages from back-end like connection with API or get data from SSR.

In both ways you have to store your JWT key and user information in DB that you must use back-end section.

Please keep in mind that DONT save sensitive data in JWT. As you saw you can decode a JWT without a key! So, it's not wise to save sensitive data in JWT.